# I want to write a YAML configuration file for the serverless framework to deploy resources (S3 buckets, DynamoDB tables) and export the configuration

Tags: amazon-s3, yaml, devops, dynamodb-queries

I am quite new to writing yaml files and having difficulty to write these files can someone please help me.

I tried to search for AWS documentation to how to write yaml files but can't understand them if possible can someone please help me with this

Comment: Is writing YAML is considered a programing question? Not sure. Read YAML specifications/documentation.